# How does Bloomberg arrive at FRN Total Price?

Tags: floating-rate

I already asked to help desk about pricing FRN, however the answer was not helpful.

I want to know how to get the value in the Invoice sector 'Total (USD)'
[image]

Using help desk's advice, I used this formula to get total price

formula : $((∑^{n-1}_{i=1}\frac{Coupon}{(1+(AR + DM)/100/freq)^i}) + \frac{FaceValue}{(1+(AR + DM)/100/freq)^{n-1}} + First Cpn)/(1+\frac{ITP+DM}{freq*100}*YF(StubPeriod))$

- AR = Assumed Rate(%)
- DM = Discount Margin(%)
- ITP = Index to Pay(%)
- YF = Year Frac
- freq = coupon payment frequency
- n = number of coupon payment

And Coupon Payment is below here

[image]
I tried many things; such as change daycount convention, method to calculate frequency, else.. , but I cannot not make accurate total price like bloomberg.

How to get accurate total price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something, but I think you're overcomplicating it.  You don't need discount margin and all that jazz.

The clean price (entered in upper left corner) is 100.311%   The face value (entered in the lower right corner) is 1,000 M. So "Principal" (next row below face value) is 1,003,110.00.

Now for the accrued. You see on the left that the quoted margin is 26 basis points, and the index rate is assumed to be 1 bp (you can change this). So the assumed coupon rate is 27 bps.

You know that the daycount convention is Actual / 360. And it says in the lower right corner that there are 71 days of accrual (actual days for your settlement date of 5/25). So, 0.000027 * 100,000,000.00 * 71 / 360 = 532.50 - exactly the number you see on the screen.

Adding up the 1,003,110.00 principal and the 532.50 accrued, you get the total of 1,003,642.50.

In the CSHF screen grab, 682.50 = 2700 * 91 / 360 corresponds to a 91-days coupon period, and 675 = 2700 * 90 / 360 to the 90-day periods.

If you prefer, you may be able to tell Bloomberg not to assume 1 bp SOFR to maturity, but to project it from some curve.

Comment: Thanks for wonderful reply. Almost everything solved except the one, the price(or value) from closed formula. My final purpose is get the price which use above formula in my question. I understand from your reply that in the 'invoice' sector, the price can be obtained easily with your suggestion. Then, when I get the price with the Pricing formula, which of number in bloomberg, I can compare with..?

Comment: I mean, I make a calculator with pricing formula and need to make it clear. I thought the total price is the price from formula so I believed my calculation output should be compared with 'total' (in the invoice sector) price. But you indicate me that it is not that difficult because it is derived from the method(that is your reply). Then which number in the picture can be derived from pricing(or valuation) formula?

Comment: Also I already saw reference: Bond Math. But in that reference, it uses total price as an input. However in my calculator, there is no input about total price. the total price is 'output'. I just use CF(682.5,675....), DM(8.997632bp), AM(1bp), ITP(1bp), Dates in the above picture. Except 'Bond Math', every logic or formula I found doesn't produce some number that matches exactly with the number in bloomberg.

Comment: Do you input the clean price (100.311)? Or do you input the discount margin (8.997632) and are asking how Bloomberg gets the price from the DM?

Comment: My input is discount margin. And the answer is above formula. But this is not exact formula. Because they are not give me exact formula, but documents about calculation rule with words not math. So I just start with guess about formula referencing with application or some practical material like Fabozzi's book, institutional rule book, else...